# How can I compare the file sizes match between duplicate directories?

Tags: bash, shell, backup, rsync, scp

I need to compare two directories to validate a backup.

Say my directory looks like the following:

```
Filename        Filesize      Filename        Filesize
user@main_server:~/mydir/     user@backup_server:~/mydir/
file1000.txt    4182410737    file1000.txt    4182410737
file1001.txt    8241410737    -                          <-- missing on backup_server!
...                           ...
file9999.txt    2410418737    file9999.txt    1111111111 <-- size != main_server
```

Is there a quick one liner that would get me close to output like:

```
Invalid Backup Files:
file1001.txt
file9999.txt
```

(with the goal to instruct the backup script to refetch these files)

I've tried to get variations of the following to no avail.

```
[main_server] $ rsync -n ~/mydir/ user@backup_server:~/mydir
```

I cannot do `rsync` to backup the directories itself because it takes way too long (8-24hrs). Instead I run multiple threads of `scp` to fetch files in batches. This completes regularly <1hr. However, occasionally I find a few files that were somehow missed (perhaps dropped connection).

Speed is a priority, so file sizes should be sufficient. But I'm open to including a `checksum`, provided it doesn't slow the process down like I find with `rsync`.

Here's my test process:

```
# Generate Large Files (1GB)
for i in {1..100}; do head -c 1073741824 </dev/urandom >foo-$i ; done

# SCP them from src to dest
for i in {1..100}; do ( scp ~/mydir/foo-$i user@backup_server:~/mydir/ & ) ; sleep 0.1 ; done

# Confirm destination has everything from source
# This is the point of the question. I've tried:

rsync -Sa ~/mydir/ user@backup_server:~/mydir
# Way too slow
```

What do you recommend?

Comment: If you have the budget, there are commercial file transfer solutions which have much better performance than SCP or SFTP.

Comment: If you already have a partial copy, as you appear to, `rsync` should be much faster than `scp`.

Comment: @John1024, Thanks. I just tried this on a test: backup 100 1GB files (filled with urandom). I `scp`'d them over first. Confirmed all 100 are there and the correct file size. Then I ran `rsync -Sa ~/source/ ~/destination` and saw all 100 files sync again, this time via `rsync`. These weren't "partial copies" as you say. They were identical copies, sent from one server to another via `scp`. What am I missing? The first `scp` took 4m44s. The rsync (after all the files were `scp`'d over) took 16m12s. I'm hoping the `scp` takes <5m and the confirmation just a few `ms`.

Comment: Interesting that I ran `rsync` again (same as my comment above), and it still found a diff and transferred 10 of the files all over again. The third time I ran it, it finished instantly. What gives?

Comment: @Ryan By default, `rsync` uses the _quick check_ method which only transfers files that differ in size or last-modified time.  What are the source & destinion filesystems (ext4, ntfs, ...)?  Alternatively, is something affecting the timestamp on either source or destination?

Comment: @John1024, Thanks! This was exactly the right direction. I added `-p` to preserve times. File sizes were the same, but times were different. No longer. `rsync` ran instantly after preserving times in `scp`. If you'd like to suggest that in an answer, I'm happy to reward your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, rsync uses the *quick check* method which only transfers files that differ in size or last-modified time. As you report that the sizes are unchanged, that would seem to indicate that the timestamps differ.  Two options to handlel this are:

- Use `-p` to preserve timestamps when transferring files.
- Use `--size-only` to ignore timestamps and transfer only files that differ in size.